# Issues with using updated mobile number to login after changing it in Azure AD using the Microsoft Graph API

Tags: c#, azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I am trying to change the mobile number of a user used as an identity in Azure AD using the user update endpoint provided by the Microsoft Graph API.

```
static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        string tenantId = <tenant-id>;
        string clientId = <client-id>;
        string clientSecret = <client-secret>;
        var objectId = <object-id>;
        var newMobile = <new-mobile-number>;

        try
        {
            string accessToken = await GetAccessToken(tenantId, clientId, clientSecret);

            await ResetMobileNumber(accessToken, objectId, newMobile );

            Console.WriteLine("Mobile number reset successfully!");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"An error occurred: {ex.Message}");
        }

    }

    static async Task<string> GetAccessToken(string tenantId, string clientId, string clientSecret)
    {
        using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
        {
            string tokenEndpoint = $"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenantId}/oauth2/v2.0/token";
            var body = $"grant_type=client_credentials&client_id={clientId}&client_secret={clientSecret}&scope=https://graph.microsoft.com/.default";

            var response = await client.PostAsync(tokenEndpoint, new StringContent(body, Encoding.UTF8, "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"));
            var responseBody = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

            var tokenJson = System.Text.Json.JsonDocument.Parse(responseBody).RootElement;
            string accessToken = tokenJson.GetProperty("access_token").GetString();

            return accessToken;
        }
    }

    static async Task ResetMobileNumber(string accessToken, string objectId, string newMobile)
    {
        using (HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient())
        {
            httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", $"Bearer {accessToken}");

            string graphApiEndpoint = $"https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{objectId}";

            var body = new
            {
                mobilePhone = newMobile
            };

            var jsonBody = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Serialize(body);
            var content = new StringContent(jsonBody, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

            var response = await httpClient.PatchAsync(graphApiEndpoint, content);
            var responseBody = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

        }
    }
```

I used the above code, the mobile number is updated in Azure AD but we can not use the new number to login with the specific user

Comment: Have you checked the user in Graph Explorer? https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer Maybe the property that you need to update is different.

Comment: Will try the explorer

Answer (score 1):

Note that, the graph endpoint you mentioned in code is to **update**
phone property in user's profile.

I ran same query as you in [**Graph Explorer**](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer) and got below response:

```json
PATCH https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/<userID>/
Content-type: application/json

{
    "mobilePhone": "+91 9133xxxxxx"
}
```

**Response:**

[image]

When I checked the same in Portal, mobile number updated in **user's profile** like below:

[image]

But if you try to login using above updated phone number, it won't work as **authentication methods** are not updated with that query .

To login with phone number, you need to add phone **authentication method** using below Graph API query:

```json
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/<userID>/authentication/phoneMethods
Content-type: application/json

{
  "phoneNumber": "+91 9133xxxxxx4",
  "phoneType": "mobile"
}
```

**Response:**
[image: ![enter image description here](https://i.imgur.com/ZLBCck4.png)]

In Azure Portal, you can check it in **Authentication methods** of user like below:

[image]

Make sure to have **`UserAuthenticationMethod.ReadWrite.All`** permission before running the query.

**Reference:**

[Create phoneMethod - Microsoft Graph v1.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/authentication-post-phonemethods?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)